# How to give title to WPF pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

It is possible to give the title to WPF window through XAML code itself at design time and it is showing the title to window at runtime.

the code in the XAML is like

```
Window1.Title="FormulaBuilder"
```

For the WPF pages also it is given in the XAML code like

```
Page1.Title="EmployeeMaster"
```

But it is not showing the title at Runtime

Then I tried to give the title through C# coding

```
Page1 obj=new Page1();
obj.Title="EmployeeMaster";
```

But it is not showing the title at runtime.

Answer (score 10):

From the documentation ([Page.Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.title.aspx)):

> **The value of the Title  property is
>   not displayed by Page, nor is it
>   displayed from the title bar of the
>   window that is hosting a Page.**
>   Instead, you set **WindowTitle**  to
>   change the title of a host window.
>
> Title can also be used to generate
>   the name of the navigation history
>   entry for a piece of navigated
>   content. The following pieces of data
>   are used to automatically construct a
>   navigation history entry name, in
>   order of precedence:
>
> ```
> * The attached Name attribute.
> * The Title property.
> * The WindowTitle property and the uniform resource identifier (URI) for the current page
> * The uniform resource identifier (URI) for the current page.
> ```

So, it seems you should try using **[Page.WindowTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.windowtitle.aspx)**. You can do this from xaml or code:

```
<Page WindowTitle="Page Title" ... >
   ...
</Page>
```

or

```
Page myPage = new Page();
myPage.WindowTitle = "Page Title";
```

Note that:

> The Page  must be the topmost piece of content in a window for WindowTitle to have an effect; if a Page  is hosted within a Frame, for example, setting WindowTitle  does not change the title of the host window.

Comment: So how do we navigate between pages without a frame? I mean if I am inside a page and I'd like to load another page.

Comment: To answer my own question, there is [NavigationWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one

```
<Window 
    x:Class="MyWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="The Title" 
    Height="300" 
    Width="300">
</window>
```

Comment: -1. The OP's looking for how to set the window title based on the title of `Page`.

Comment: This does not work with Page the question asks for Page (not Window).

Answer (score 0):

For pages we suppose to user "Title" property

```
<Page  Title="Page Title Goes here" ... >   ...</Page>
```