# WPF: Change Window's Title on every Page Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I have a `WPF application` consist of a single window `MainWindow.xaml`

with title **Sample_Window**

```
<Window
   Title="Sample_Window">
<Grid>
   <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Source="/Page1.xaml" />
<Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: See this image]

and three pages:

```
    Page1.xaml
    Page2.xaml
    Page3.xaml
```

What my question is that I want to change the title of the MainWindow on every *page navigation*

for e.g when I land to `Page1.xaml` title should be `Sample_Window-Page1` etc.

I've tried below piece of code in `XAML`:(didn't work)

```
<Page 
    WindowTitle="Sample_Window-Page1"
    Title="Page1">
</Page>
```

Also, in **CS**:(didn't work)

```
Page1 mypage= new Page1();
mypage.WindowTitle="Sample_Window-Page1";
```

I also gone through this question [How to give title to WPF pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354200/how-to-give-title-to-wpf-pages)

But didn't get solution to my problem. The title still remains same as **Sample_Window**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case your Title of Page1 is generated dynamically("Customer `Joe Smith` Details"), you may have a property on Page1ViewModel called Title. In this case you can simply bind to Frame's Content's DataContext from your MainWindow:

```
<Window 
  Title="{Binding ElementName=mainFrame, Path=Content.DataContext.Title}">
  <Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Source="/Page1.xaml" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

If your Page1 Title is static text (Use Title instead of WindowTitle property), then just bind directly to it from your Main Window:

```
<Window 
  Title="{Binding ElementName=mainFrame, Path=Content.Title}">
  <Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Source="/Page1.xaml" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Where do I need to write this? In the <Page> or in the <Window>

Comment: As I wrote "from your MainWindow" it should be placed in <Window>, I'll update the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Well it still doesn't work.. Here's what I did.. <Page Title="Sample_Window-Page1" />  <Window Title="{Binding ElementName=mainFrame, Path=Content.DataContext.Title}" />

Comment: If you are using DataContext.Title you have to make sure that Page1 has DataContext and in the DataContext there is Title property. This is useful if window title is dynamic. Otherwise just bind to Content.Title(Make sure Page1 has Title property setup).

Answer (score 0):

The above did not work for me because it loaded [myPage1] when running the app.  I display [myPage1] from a button click on MainWindow so to display the page with a static title I added the required title text to the navigation.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<DockPanel> <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame"/> </DockPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs in the button_click method

```
_mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new [myPage1] (Title= "what ever you want displayed"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.Title = "Sample_Window-Page1";
```

Can you try this ? Frames dont change the window so the title stays, you should update the window's title every change of your pages.

Comment: No it will not work, as this.Title is the property for changing page titlle