# How to set title of a page that hosted by a frame window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a frame window that are used to host pages.

```
//inside frame window
public partial class FrameWindow : Window

{

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new Example_Page();
    }
}
```

I saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354200/how-to-give-title-to-wpf-pages) but its not worked since the page hosted by a window frame. So how do i set a title of a page and display on the top bar of the window? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make your Example_Page expose a property (for example `Title`) that denotes the title and then make the FrameWindow Title property bind to that property. An example:

In the markup for your `FrameWindow` bind the title like this:

```
<Window ...
Title="{Binding Content.Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

And in your Example_Page code behind expose a property like this:

```
public partial class Example_Page : ....
{
    ...
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Note that if you set the Content of the FrameWindow to any content that doesn't expose this property the Title will be blank.